# How do I configure SMTP for DB2 9.5?

Tags: smtp, db2

During install I know the wizard asks for an SMTP server for notification. But I can't find these properties now when we really need it.

We're running on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to  connect with SYSADMIN rights and issue a command like this one:

`update admin cfg using smtp_server put_smtp_server_hostname_here`

Then restart the DAS server:

`eb2admin stop`

`eb2admin start`

Comment: You can't do this from the gui?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Searching does'nt return anything GUI related. Sorry.